# what is the meaning of this code ..[select @a:=password(?)]

Tags: sql

I have not seen it before. What's the meaning behind this statement?

```
select @a:=password(?)
```

Comment: need more details....moreover `sql` is just language, tag appropriate database name like `mysql`, `sql server`, `oracle` etc

Answer (score 4):

Without any context, it's easy to make a good guess by breaking this down:

- `select` should be familiar to you
- `@a` is probably a variable name; a lot of databases use @ as a prefix in the same way that languages like PHP and Perl use $
- `:=` is a common way of spelling the assignment operator, to distinguish from `=` which is comparison in SQL
- `password()` looks like a function call; probably it runs some hashing algorithm so that the password isn't stored in plain text
- `?` is generally used as a placeholder where the user's input should be placed in a parameterised query (if you don't know about those, look them up, they're the best way of making your SQL secure)

So the statement probably means "run the password function over the user-supplied data, and assign it to the variable @a for use in a later statement".